# Implement passthroughViews in a custom UIPresentationController

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm implementing a custom presentation controller that is similar to `UIPopupPresentationController`, but with some added features.  Now, I'd like it to support `passthroughViews` functionality just like UIPopupPresentationController does.

I'm having a hard time finding a way to do this.  I have a dimming view that covers the views below the popover and dims them, and figure I'd implement `hitTest:` on that, and return `nil` when events should be passed through, but the problem is that UIKit puts a view of the private class UITransitionView at the bottom of the hierarchy, and I can't seem to get past that.

Any ideas?